# Disable service workers or workbox in nuxtjs app

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I'm trying to to generate a nuxt app using the `nuxt generate` command. I want to use it by opening the `index.html` file in the `dist` folder. Everything works except for one page where I've some static assets loading. I'm getting the following error:

> DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at
>   'file:///Users/web-app/dist/_nuxt/a694c9435aa306bfdc85.worker.js'
>   cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.
>       at new e.exports (file:///Users/web-app/dist/_nuxt/ddebbd7698f3519f1f2a.js:2:387818)
>       at Object.253 (file:///Users/web-app/dist/_nuxt/ddebbd7698f3519f1f2a.js:2:41913)
>       at c (file:///Users/web-app/dist/_nuxt/849a5edcbb351f009715.js:1:534)
>       at Module.318 (file:///Users/web-app/dist/_nuxt/58dff71a539121ee82b0.js:1:7082)
>       at c (file:///Users/web-app/dist/_nuxt/849a5edcbb351f009715.js:1:534)

Here's my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
    '~/assets/css/all.css'
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    '@nuxtjs/toast'
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: './tailwind.config.js'
      }
    },
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */

    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (!isDev) {
        // relative links, please.
        config.output.publicPath = "./_nuxt/";
      }
      return config;
    }
  },

  router: {
    mode: "hash"
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to disable the service workers in my app.

Comment: Try using something like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) instead of loading the files directly. Origin permissions on `file://` are pretty different from running as a web server.

Comment: @abraham it is a situation where I cannot create an http server by calling `serve` command. Users are going to double click on the `index.html` file to open the page. They cannot perform `serve` command. Just wondering if there's any way to remove the `service worker`.

Comment: Try disabling [`autoRegister`](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/modules/workbox.html#options)

Comment: @abraham it did not work. Still showing the same error message.

Answer (score 7):

You can [disable](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/setup.html) the `workbox` sub-module in `nuxt.config.js`.

```js
modules: [
  ['@nuxtjs/pwa', { workbox: false }],
],
```

Comment: I would just remove the `@nuxtjs/pwa` module completely then.

Comment: I tried removing pwa, but still get lots of browsers trying to request sw.js, resulting in 404 errors.

Comment: @Devin remove your service worker manually then. It has been previously registered https://love2dev.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-a-service-worker/

Comment: `modules: [
  ['@nuxtjs/pwa', { workbox: { enabled: false } }],
],` will disable and unregister the service worker